# How to download a Minecraft world file from google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been given access to a Minecraft server that is being hosted on a virtual machine on google cloud. I've tried downloading it using the scp command but I'm not sure what directory the world file would be in. Can anybody help? I've tried lots of things and nothing has worked yet.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the directory for Minecraft, I would say that all depends on the installation and configuration of the server.

In the official documentation for Minecraft there is a page that can help you [*Where are Minecraft files stored?*](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131551-Where-are-Minecraft-files-stored-). According to this document for a Linux installation it should be:

```
~ is your home directory, usually /home/YOURNAME, so ~/.minecraft would be /home/YOURNAME/.minecraft/.
```

But if this server have been installed following the [official documentation from GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server) it should be on:

```
/home/minecraft
```

Take in consideration that if another guide has followed or if the administrator decided to use another directory it will be in another path.

But if the name of the directory is minecraft  you could find it using the following command:

```
find / -name "minecraft"
```

If you have access to GCP you can download the files using the [SSH in the browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#transferbrowser)

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the [VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.126753933.1474630505.1601299628-638966553.1591892739&_gac=1.23451720.1601304336.Cj0KCQjwk8b7BRCaARIsAARRTL4r-A0fyXLlGGLvmXQdlaX27Vc7mKNvOU4qXuBFIGG-ptw3nCmkUREaAlMwEALw_wcB) page.
2. In the list of virtual machine instances, click **SSH** in the row of the instance that you want to connect to.
3. After the connection is established, click the gear icon in the upper right of the **SSH from the Browser** window and select **Download file** to download a file from the instance.

To download the files using scp you can use something like:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key username@ip-address:remote-file-path local-file-path
```

If you have not yet applied a public key to your Google Cloud Console project or instance, [obtain an SSH key pair and apply the public SSH key file](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) to your project or instance.

You can obtain more alternatives on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files)